# Performance considerations about html canvas, context and imageData when making bitmap manipulations

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Having not found one, I'm trying to write a lightweight library to manipulate bitmaps using JavaScript. For a start, I'd need, at least, three functions: `newImage(w,h)`, `getPixel(img,x,y)`, `setPixel(img,x,y)`. The problem is, HTML doesn't have an editable "image" type, but three different things (canvas, context and imageData) with different purposes. Which exactly shoud `getImage` return, and how should the `getPixel` and `setPixel` functions work?

Comment: My current approach would be to actually return the canvas, the context and the imageData all at the same time on `newImage`. On `getPixel` I'd perform a `image.imageData.data.slice` to get the 4 desired values (rgba). `setPixel` would be kind of broken, though, as I'd have to update `image.imageData.data` and then call `context.putImageData` to update the canvas, and this would make modifying a pixel horribly slow. So I'd need a last function, `update`. The whole idea seems horrible, thought, because I don't understand those objects well enough to decide something like that.

Comment: And current documentation is really poor and not aiming for my needs.